# Access mysql remote database from command line

Tags: mysql, shell, mysql-error-2003

I have a server with Rackspace. I want to access the database from my local machine command line.

I tried like:

```
mysql -u username -h my.application.com -ppassword
```

But it gives an error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000):
>
> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my.application.com' (10061)

What causes this error and how can I connect to the remote database?

Comment: `10061` = *Connection refused*

Comment: It's best to use the `-p` flag without the password, so the password isn't saved in your bash history.

Answer (score 487):

To directly login to a remote mysql console, use the below command:

```
mysql -u {username} -p'{password}' \
    -h {remote server ip or name} -P {port} \
    -D {DB name}
```

For example

```
mysql -u root -p'root' \
        -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 \
        -D local
```

**no space after -p** as specified in the [Using Options on the Command Line](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/command-line-options.html) documentation

It will take you to the mysql console directly by switching to the mentioned database.

Comment: To specify the database name we need to add -D . mysql -u {username} -p{password} -h {remote server ip} -D {DB name}

Comment: what if we need to specify the specific PORT?

Comment: Didn't work in Terminal on MacOS High Sierra Version 10.13.3

Comment: **no intervening space** after `-p`
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/command-line-options.html

Comment: Is interesting that in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/command-line-options.html does not do mention about the `-D` parameter

Comment: I was able to connect to the database without typing any space between -u and the username, -p and the password, -h and the host. Like this: `mysql -u$username -p$password -h$host -D $database_name`.

Comment: If this is for the case of a user typing at the console you should easily avoid passing the password in the command line as unencrypted text. Just use `-p` and the rest as specified. The execution of the script will interrogate you for the password securely.

Comment: For example `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -D local -p`

Answer (score 47):

simply put this on terminal at ubuntu:

```
mysql -u username -h host -p
```

Now hit enter

terminal will ask you password, enter the password and you are into database server

Answer (score 36):

edit my.cnf file:

`vi /etc/my.cnf`:

make sure that:

`bind-address=YOUR-SERVER-IP`

and if you have the line:

`skip-networking`

make sure to comment it:

`#skip-networking`

don't forget to restart:

`/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`

Comment: bind-address=YOUR-SERVER-IP . here which IP i need to mention is it remote server IP?

Comment: @user1986299 no, your need your server's IP (not the remote)

Comment: i AM GETTING ERROR:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'115.119.117.94' (using password: YES)

Comment: you should grant yourself access... login your DB from the local server by typing mysql and then: `grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by 'your-password'`

Comment: NEVER grant 'root'@'%' this is a huge security no no!

Comment: for mariadb i edited /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

Comment: MySQL 5.7 is under /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf

Comment: @alfasin this is a small tweak with a deep impact, thank you!

Answer (score 23):

For Mac, use the following command:

```
mysql -u app -h hostaddress -P port -D dbname -p
```

and then enter the password when prompted.

Comment: Don't try to enter the password after -p flag, that won't work. As mentioned above you'll be prompted for the password value later on. This is done so that there are no unmasked credentials stored in the terminal history.

Answer (score 18):

Try this command `mysql -uuser -hhostname -PPORT -ppassword`.

I faced a similar situation and later when mysql port for host was entered with the command, it was solved.

Comment: `mysql -u testuser -h 192.168.**.* -P 3306 -p password` worked for me

Answer (score 16):

If you want to not use ssh tunnel, in **my.cnf** or **mysqld.cnf** you must change **127.0.0.1** with your local ip address (**192.168.1.100**) in order to have access over the Lan. example bellow:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Search for **bind-address** in **my.cnf** or **mysqld.cnf**

```
bind-address            =  127.0.0.1
```

and change **127.0.0.1** to **192.168.1.100** ( local ip address )

```
bind-address            =  192.168.1.100
```

To apply the change you made, must restart mysql server using next command.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Modify user **root** for lan acces ( run the query's bellow in remote server that you want to have access )

```
root@192.168.1.100:~$ mysql -u root -p
```

..

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If you want to have access only from specific ip address , change **'root'@'%'** to **'root'@'( ip address or hostname)'**

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'192.168.1.100' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.100' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then you can connect:

```
nobus@xray:~$ mysql -h 192.168.1.100 -u root -p
```

**tested on ubuntu 18.04 server**

Comment: The best answer! Thanks

Answer (score 11):

1. try `telnet 3306`. If it doesn't open connection, either there is a firewall setting or the server isn't listening (or doesn't work).
2. run `netstat -an` on server to see if server is up.
3. It's possible that you don't allow remote connections.

For more details see:

- [How Do I Enable Remote Access To MySQL Database Server?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Answer (score 7):

I assume you have MySQL installed on your machine. Execute the command below after filling missing details:

```
mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -hHOSTNAME -P3306
```

Answer (score 5):

mysql servers are usually configured to listen only to localhost (127.0.0.1), where they are used by web applications.

If that is your case but you have SSH access to your server, you can create an ssh tunnel and connect through that.

On your local machine, create the tunnel.

```
ssh -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 -N $user@$remote_host
```

(this example uses local port 3307, in case you also have mysql running on your local machine and using the standard port 3306)

Now you should be ale to connect with

```
mysql -u $user -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307
```

Comment: How do I forward multiple ports to different servers at the same time? My use case -- we have several production Wordpress servers that are behind a firewall. Also assume that each of them uses a different SSH key to allow access.

Comment: @RodrikTheReader : just repeat the commands with different port numbers and the appropriate $user@$host variables. You can also add different `-i $identity_file` to the ssh command if you have different keys.

Answer (score 4):

There is simple command.

```
mysql -h {hostip} -P {port} -u {username} -p {database}
```

Example

```
mysql -h 192.16.16.2 -P 45012 -u rockbook -p rockbookdb
```

Comment: {hostip} will not add any kind of port detail like 192.10.10.26::45124

Answer (score 4):

you can use the following code to connect to a remote MY SQL database

```
mysql -u {database_user} -p{db_password} -h {host_name} -P {port_number}
mysql -u your_db_username -p'your_password' -h your-company.aws.com -P 3306
```

Answer (score 3):

Must check whether incoming access to port 3306 is block or not by the firewall.

Comment: How can I check this

Answer (score 1):

this solution worked for me:

On your remote machine (example: 295.13.12.53) has access to your target remote machine (which runs mysql server)

```
ssh -f -L 295.13.12.53:3306:10.18.81.36:3306 user@295.13.12.53
```

Explained:

```
ssh -f -L your_ssh_mashine_ipaddress:your_ssh_mashine_local_port:target_ipaddress:target_port user@your_ip_address -N
```

your_ssh_mashine_ipaddress - it is not local ip address, it is ip address
that you ssh to, in this example 295.13.12.53

your_ssh_mashine_local_port -this is custom port not 22, in this example it is 3306.

target_ipaddress - ip of the machine that you trying to dump DB.

target_port - 3306 this is real port for MySQL server.

user@your_ip_address - this is ssh credentials for the ssh mashine that you connect

Once all this done then go back to your machine and do this:

```
mysqldump -h 295.13.12.53 -P 3306 -u username -p db_name > dumped_db.sql
```

Will ask for password, put your password and you are connected.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Its working:

**mysql -h {hostname}  -u{username}  -p{password}  -N  -e  "{query to execute}"**

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me in mysql 8, replace `hostname` with your hostname and `port_number` with your port_number,  you can also change your mysql_user if he is not root

```
      mysql --host=host_name --port=port_number -u root -p
```

[Further Information Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should put your password with 'p'

```
mysql -u root -u 1.1.1.1 -p'MyPass'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was too getting the same error.
But found it useful by creating new mysql user on remote mysql server ans then connect. Run following command on remote server:

```
CREATE USER 'openvani'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'openvani'@'localhost WITH GRANT 
OPTION;
CREATE USER 'openvani'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'openvani'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now you can connect with remote mysql with following command.

```
mysql -u openvani -h 'any ip address'-p
```

Here is the full post:

http://openvani.com/blog/connect-remotely-mysql-server/

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, try Visual Studio Code with MySQL plugins, an easy and integrated way to  access MySQL data on a windows machine. And the database tables listed and can execute any custom queries.

Answer (score 0):

If port is default, some version required data base name which you trying to connect.

```
mysql -u <<your username>> -h <<your host>> <<your db name >> -p
```

This will prompt password Then type your password. If port is not default 3306
Then:

```
mysql -u <<your username>> -h <<your host>> -P <<your port>> <<your db name >> -p
```