# How to create a table in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to create a table in a MySQL Database with PHP. This is my try:

```
$dbhost = 'rdbms.strato.de';
$dbusername = 'Userxxx';
$dbuserpass = 'Passwordxxx';
$dbname = 'DBxxx';

$link_id = mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbuserpass);
echo "success in database connection.";

if (!mysql_select_db($dbname)) die(mysql_error());
echo "success in database selection.";

$result = "CREATE TABLE address_book (first_name VARCHAR(25), last_name VARCHAR(25), phone_number VARCHAR(15))";

if (mysql_query($result)){
 echo "TABLE created.";
}

else {
 echo "Error in CREATE TABLE.";
}
```

But this give me the error

```
success in database connection.Access denied for user XXX to database XXX
```

I search a lot but find no successfull solution. Have anyone an idea?

Comment: Does your MySQL user has write access to this database? If not, look at this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Comment: Seems like it's not letting you select DBxxx. Does your user have the right permissions?

Comment: Your current user `$dbusername` for the connection has not the rights to create a table `address_book` in the seleted DB `$dbname`.

Comment: You shouldn't use any mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since php 5.5 and completely removed in php 7.0

Comment: Note for some of the above. The error is _before_ trying to create the table.

Comment: You don't have needed privileges for user `Userxxx`, check your mysql user settings on strato.de host provider

Comment: Try it with your "root" user, then

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in _meow_ code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting without involving PHP:

```
mysql -u Userxxx -h rdbms.strato.de -pPasswordxxx
```

If this doesn't work, and I suspect it won't, contact your database administrator to reset your password.

If the password isn't the problem, the remote machine may not be ready to accept your connection.  See [Access remote database from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872543/access-remote-database-from-command-line) for more on this.

If you can get in, then try to access the database you want:

```
USE DBxxx;
SHOW TABLES;
```

Thing is, PHP isn't your problem here; it's the connection.  So that's what to investigate.

...and when you get that established, you might look into updating your code; `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I need some clarification about your hostname,username,password,database name.How ever following code will works in my local server.If you have any doubt about my code please share your host name,password,dbname,etc.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbusername = 'root';
$dbuserpass = '';
$dbname = 'test';

    $link_id = mysqli_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbuserpass,$dbname);
echo "success in database connection.";



$result = "CREATE TABLE address_book (first_name VARCHAR(25), last_name VARCHAR(25), phone_number VARCHAR(15))";

if (mysqli_query($link_id,$result)){
 echo "TABLE created.";
}

else {
 echo "Error in CREATE TABLE.";
}
```