# database connection error while connecting database in live server error 1045

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

my .env file setup like this on the live server. but while I am

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=onlyaruv_notepad-apps
DB_USERNAME=onlyaruv_notepad
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

the error was

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'onlyaruv_notepad'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = ih76632@gmail.com limit 1)
```

I access my ssh via putty using this host and password 
http://5.100.156.10:2082 I am confused .

Comment: did you run php artisan config:cache on the server?

Comment: did try to run your mysql on visual database design tool like workbech or phpmyadmin

Comment: Run composer dump-autoload

Comment: try to connect from putty
[Access remote database from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872543/access-remote-database-from-command-line). Disregard "remote", you can put your `127.0.0.1`

Comment: `mysql -u onlyaruv_notepad -pmypassword -h 127.0.0.1 "onlyaruv_notepad-apps"` Note that `-p` needs to be "glued" to your pass (no spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Have you given All privileges to onlyaruv_notepad this user?
if you not please give all privileges to the user.
still, The problem not solved check host is correct or not.
(change DB_HOST=127.0.0.1  to DB_HOST=localhost

Comment: @Sharifur Have you given All privileges to onlyaruv_notepad this user?

Comment: yes, I do but still the same error what can I do for this?

Comment: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'onlyaruv_napps'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = r@gmail.com limit 1)

Answer (score 0):

Check your database connection carefully. If it does not work then
Run the following artisan command and try again

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: did every thing whatever you say. but no result