# How do I connect to my database URL (retrieved from heroku) using mysql installed on my local xampp in windows

Tags: mysql, windows, heroku

I have heroku app running using a Jaws Maria db as a add on, I want to access the database using xampp's mysql on windows 7 machine. I got my database url via

`heroku config:get JAWSDB_MARIA_URL --app MYAPPNAME`

which got me a string like

`mysql://username:password@serveraddress:3306/dbname`

i'm trying to access this database url via the command from my cmd

`E:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql -u username -h serveraddress.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -D dbname -p`

accoring to the thread [Access mysql remote database from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872543/access-mysql-remote-database-from-command-line)

after providing the password im getting an error

`Can't connect to MySQL server on 'serveraddress.amazonaws.com' (10060 "Unknown error")`

Whereas if i try to connect to ths database from c9.io I can access it using the command

`mysql -u username -h serveraddress.amazonaws.com:3306 -p`

Can anyone help me so that I can access it from xampp's mysql in windows as well. Cant figure out what am I missing here

Comment: Have you tried using postgres? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#connecting-to-a-database-remotely

Comment: no I made it with mysql