# Unable to controlling remotely mysql server

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I need to access a mysql database remotely (from another device connected to the same network). Searching on internet i've knowed Searching that I have to enable remote control, but I couldn't. How can I do?

When I connect, after asking me for the password, it gives me this error:
    `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.206' (111).`
I tried to follow some guides until you have to comment bind-address in my.cnf, because "my.cnf" file is like this:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

so i can't enable the remote control. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access mysql remote database from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872543/access-mysql-remote-database-from-command-line)

Comment: Your server probably has SELinux enabled which means you need to enable inbound access to the port 3306/tcp. What Linux distro are you using?

Comment: Is there a `bind-address` in one of the include files?  Is it under `[mysqld]`?