# Connection string for MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, remote-access

I'm running CentOS v7.9 with MariaDB v5.5.68. I'm trying to access the MariaDB databases from a Win10 machine using Visual Studio Code with SQLTools & MySQL/MariaDB extensions.

I have configured MariaDB for remote access per this link:  [Configuring MariaDB for Remote Client Access](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/)

```
[mysqld]
skip-networking=0
skip-bind-address
```

I created the users and added the privileges - tested by logging in locally with 'bob' and viewing permissions in `mysql.user`. (BTW, in case not readily apparent, the UID, host, and PWD aren't real.)

```
CREATE USER 'bob'@'1.2.3.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPWD';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'bob'@'1.2.3.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPWD';
```

However, when I try to log in remotely (from another Linux box) using `mysql -u userID -h hostIP -p`, I get the error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000):  Can't connect to MySQL server on '1.2.3.4' (110)
```

When I try to make the database connection using VS Code, SQLTools tells me I've connected, but it won't show any tables, I'm not able to make any queries, and I get this error:  `Request connection/GetChildrenForTreeItemRequest failed with message: Handshake inactivity timeout`.

I have reviewed [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872543/access-mysql-remote-database-from-command-line) and others, but still can't get the connection to work.

UPDATED for clarity - provides mysql.user and netstat info:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select user, host from mysql.user;
+------+-------------+
| user | host        |
+------+-------------+
| bob  | 10.0.2.15   |      # Can't connect
| rob  | 127.0.0.1   |      # Logs in locally via command line
| root | 127.0.0.1   |      # Logs in locally via command line
| bob  | 192.168.0.% |      # Can't connect
| root | 192.168.0.% |      # Can't connect
| root | ::1         |      # Logs in locally via command line
| rob  | localhost   |      # Logs in locally via command line
| root | localhost   |      # Logs in locally via command line
+------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)


$ > netstat -tulpen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27         33813      -
```

Any help is much appreciated as I've been working this problem for 2+ days and have not made any headway.

Comment: This post may be helpful: [Access mysql remote database from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872543/access-mysql-remote-database-from-command-line)

Comment: I added additional information from mysql.user and netstat. For @user9938 - Yes, I've seen this page, as indicated above.